# Error en método haciendo uso de Tuple c#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código el cual estoy tratando de hacer uso de tuple para devolver 2 valores pero me arroja un error al momento de poner el return.

```
 public Tuple<DateTime,DateTime> Obtener_Fecha_Acceso_Sin_Label_Fec(DateTime dtpFecIni,DateTime dtpFecFin)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT ID,FechaInicio,FechaFin from TBL_FECHA_PROCESO ";
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader buscar = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (buscar.Read() == true)
                {
                    dtpFecIni = Convert.ToDateTime(buscar["FechaInicio"]);
                    dtpFecFin = Convert.ToDateTime(buscar["FechaFin"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro No Fue Encontrado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    //txtid.Text = "";
                    //txtid.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (command != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)command).Dispose();
                }

                //if (conn != null)
                //{
                //    ((IDisposable)conn).Dispose();
                //}                    
            }
        }
        return (dtpFecIni, dtpFecFin); -- AQUI MUESTRA ERROR
```

Como se ve en el codigo señalo donde se produce el error y aqui pongo el detalle del mismo.

> Error CS0029  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
> '(System.DateTime dtpFecIni, System.DateTime dtpFecFin)' en
> 'System.Tuple<System.DateTime, System.DateTime>'

De antemano agradezco su ayuda guiandome sobre mi error.

Comment: Que es dtpFecIni y dtpFecFin, son dateTimePicker?

Comment: Este artículo, [C# 7.0: Tuples explained](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained), te da los detalles que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás  retornando un Value_Tuple y deberías retornar un Tuple. Puedes hacer  una de dos:

1. Retornar un Tuple:

   ```
    return new Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>(dtpFecIni, dtpFecFin);
   ```
2. Cambiar la declaración de la función:

   ```
   public  (DateTime FecIni,DateTime FecFin) Obtener_Fecha_Acceso_Sin_Label_Fec(DateTime dtpFecIni,DateTime dtpFecFin)
   ```

Toma nota que en el segundo caso tendrías que cambiar a todos los que llaman a esa función.